# Folder permission in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net application. There is a folder in the project that users upload images and files to that folder.

I want to restrict users, that each user sees only his files. How can I do this?
Because files are uploaded in folder, users may access them by browsing file urls.

Comment: How about using asp.net membership to control access. I think that is the "right" way.

Answer (score 2):

One way is you could store the files inside the username of a folder, and your parameter which allows you specify a path always assumes you are talking about after the username...much like how shared web hosting must work.

Regardless, you should secure each folder for each user if there was some flaw in your code or whatever...

e.g. the physical file structure with each users files

```
C:\TheProject\Uploads\UserA\Images
C:\TheProject\Uploads\UserB\Images
C:\TheProject\Uploads\UserC\Images
```

your web app's url where you show the files for the *currently logged on user*. If UserA is logged on, show the files inside the appropriate folder etc

Happy paths:

```
http://example.com/browsefiles/?path=images
http://example.com/browsefiles/?path=docs
```

Unhappy paths:

```
http://example.com/browsefiles/?path=../UserA/images
http://example.com/browsefiles/?path=../../web.config
```

So obviously put some very tight checking around what input you accept...perhaps even a whitelist instead...if the query by the user doesn't match the whitelist, block it. In this scenario, you'd probably want to err on the side of blocking a legitimate request than allowing a malicious one.

**Edit**
If users can access the files without going through your web application (can we assume Intranet app here???) perhaps through a file share/network share/ftp then you could try a couple of options

- Each user in your app is a user on the server (local user) so they would have a username and password on the server (which your app would need to authenticate against) but would allow you to set permissions on each folder/file on the server to a local user, OR
- This might be easier if you have Active Directory setup and can use Windows Authentication and that way you could both impersonate your web app and secure the files/folders using the user's active directory account.

You might need to consult http://serverfault.com if you need help with Active Directory or Accounts on Windows servers

Comment: i want to acess files directly, not by a asp.net page and querystring. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create web.config in image folder and use FormsAuhentication 
in web.config :

```
  <authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>  // anonymous user
  </authorization>
```

Comment: This doesn't limit that a user only sees his own files.